# Scaleable size of application with non 9-patch buttons

Tags: android

I'm currently learning android development, and before I get too stuck in to a large project, I decided I would need to learn about making an application accessible from as many devices as possible.

So I have a test application using `RelativeLayout`. The top-level activity has 6 large menu buttons on it. These buttons are square graphical images (not 9-patch buttons as they are - to my knowledge - too graphically primitive). On the device I'm using for testing, these buttons appear in a perfect 2x3 arrangement like such:

[image: Buttons laid out perfectly in 3x2 arrangement]

However, when I try and run this application on a larger device, the buttons will appear like so:

[image]

Is there a way to scale non-9-patch buttons based on the size of the screen, so that they will always appear like the first image? Is this recommended? If not, is there an alternative way of doing such a layout for different screen sizes?

My ideal layout would be scalable across different devices, like so:

[image]

Comment: Set `android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"`, `android:layout_marginLRight="20dip"`, `android:layout_marginTop="20dip"` and  `android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"` to the right columnt buttons and then Set `android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"`, `android:layout_marginLRight="10dip"`, `android:layout_marginTop="20dip"` and  `android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"`

Comment: @g00dy I'm not sure exactly, but will this not scale properly? I'm guessing that using constants for layout probably won't. Is that correct?

Comment: Yeah for sure, but try it out, just to see if the buttons are stretched accordingly. With the margins set it normally should; also it should look the same on some different devices I guess. Also the `android:layout_weight="1"` attribute can help in such occasions.

Comment: You can scale those images but it seems to be more of a layout issue(as you use `RelativeLayout`, did you use `alignParentLeft/Right`(which would explain the gap between them)?). Provide images for different screen sizes.

Comment: I have added my intended layout as an image.

Comment: @g00dy Do you think I should be using a `LinearLayout` with weighted values then?

Comment: I think so, but looking at the three new screenshots you pasted - I cound't see a link between the outer magrin of the buttons across the different screen sizes. You want it fixed (using the fisrt suggestion) or to be with weghted values for each button (you can try both and see which one fits best).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using similar menu. And here is first row of it. The buttons in this menu has labels too.

```
        <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
                    android:gravity="center" >

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dip" >

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/screen_home_btn_profile"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@drawable/selector_ic_my_profile" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:paddingBottom="5dip" >

                            <TextView
                                style="@style/label_text_style_home_screen"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="@string/screen_home_label_my" />

                            <TextView
                                style="@style/label_text_style_home_screen"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="@string/screen_home_label_profile"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dip" >

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/screen_home_btn_application"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@drawable/selector_ic_my_application" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:paddingBottom="5dip" >

                            <TextView
                                style="@style/label_text_style_home_screen"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="@string/screen_home_label_my" />

                            <TextView
                                style="@style/label_text_style_home_screen"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="@string/screen_home_label_application"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
```

It seems you are giving outer margins to the buttons. Align them in center and give spaces between 2 buttons and not the screen border & buttons.

Comment: You can use layouts inside layouts?! Madness! I need to go watch Inception now.

Comment: Ok I just got it working. Your example allowed me to get the exact layout I wanted whilst keeping it scalable. Thank you sir!